# Protractor screenshot plugin

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am currently using the Custom framework for protractor end to end automation. I saw screenshot plugin is used Jasmine framework specifically. If I want to use Protractor screenshot plugin for Custom framework, how I can approach.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter